# Angular - making a Toggle to replace divs

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to make a toggle switch to replace a section on a page with another div of content

```
<!-- Toggle - Changes page layout on Click-->
<div class="content">
  <p class="leftBox" >option 1</p>
  <label class=" switch" >
    <input type="checkbox" (click)="toggle()" >
    <span class="slider round" ></span>
  </label>
  <p class="rightBox" >option 2</p>
</div>


<div class="page1Text">


<!-- Page Content -->

</div>

<!-- next button -->
<div class="content">
  <button type="button" class="  mat-raised-button buttontxt" (click)="nextpage1()">Next</button>
</div>
</div>


<!-- page content 2 -->
<ng-container *ngIf="show">
<div class ="page2" >
  

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div class= "content text-center">
      
  <!-- next button - Link to either Growth or Mindset page, dependant on which is toggled -->
  <div class="content">
    <button type="button" class=" pam-button mat-raised-button buttontxt" (click)="nextpage2()">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
</ng-container>
```

and my typescript

```
 toggle(){
    this.show = !this.show;

    if(this.show)
      this.switch = "Hide";
    else
      this.switch = "Show";
  }
```

The page 2 content shows and hides fine but I want to replace/hide the page 1 content on a toggle switch and vice versa, but unsure on how to do this

Comment: Are you trying to make a pagination ? If this is the case, the question you are asking is out of context (meaning, the way you chose is not the right way to do this)

Comment: No, that part is sorted elsewhere, this is just trying to replace/hide a part of a HTML page and show something different via a toggle button - for example, replace "Div1 contents" with "Div2 contents"  on the same page

Comment: Ok, in that case I'll answer you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a toggle, you just have to use templates when the conditions are met.

I'll give you a generic example with a more "clean" syntax :

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="show; then showTpl; else hideTpl">
</ng-container>

<button (click)="show = !show">
  Toggle view
</button>

<ng-template #showTpl>
  This part is shown when show variable is set to true
</ng-template>

<ng-template #hideTpl>
  This part is shown when show variable is set to false
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Fantastic! its 90% of the way there, my only now is that it requires 2 clicks to toggle between them after the first press

Comment: I cannot figure this one out, its weird, it switches the content fine the first time but on any other click it requires 2 presses to change